# Golang hierarchical routing

Tags: go

I want to make RESTful API which has multi layer route like :

```
/api/auhtorization/getUserdata
```

where **api** stands for webservice name,
**auhtorization** stands for a function to check validation of token.
and **getUserdata** stands for a function that get specific user data ( if only request past authorization level )

```
func main(){
   http.HandleFunc("api/", func(rw, req){
      http.HandleFunc("authorization/", func(){

         if (auth passed)
         {
            http.HandleFunc("getUserdata", getUserFunction())
         }

      })

   })
}
```

I know above code isn't a good example but I seek for best practice or framework for doing this.
Any answer will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can have a look at how the Kubernetes API Server is doing it in the `DefaultBuildHandlerChain`, as we described in https://blog.openshift.com/kubernetes-deep-dive-api-server-part-1/

Comment: My recommendation is to have a look at some insightful REST API design principles like [Richardson Maturity Model](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) before actually designing RESTful APIs.

Comment: how do I implements those theories? @Jermin

Comment: After you are done with your design you could use [HTTPRouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter), or [Gorilla Mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) just to mention a few. But I guess my comment was more of an existential question than a solution. Why would you want such a feature? Isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: Second @JerminBazazian note - by the name alone, `getUserdata` implies an RPC API, not a REST API.

Comment: @Adrian but the first sentence talks about REST not RPC. And I am not sure if you noticed by there is a reason that Richardson Maturity Model is called **Maturity Model** and not just **Model**.

Comment: Yes, I know. I was agreeing with you, hence "second @JerminBazazian note".

Comment: @Adrian, oops my bad

Answer (score 1):

Your first (outmost) call to `http.HandleFunc` is correct - it maps a route to a handler function. The rest of the code implies a misunderstanding of how that works, though. The handler function will be called when a request matching that route comes in; when a handling a request is not the time to register additional routes, because route registration is not request-specific, and it's too late to modify the routing table for the current request. The last call makes even less sense: you can't register a route based on whether the current request is authorized. As soon as one authorized request comes in, that route will be registered for all *future* requests, regardless of whether those requests are authorized, and will not make any different for the current request.

What you want, most likely, is to replace both of the nested calls to `http.HandleFunc` with calls to handler methods, e.g.:

```
func main(){
    http.HandleFunc("/api/", func(rw, req){
        if strings.HasPrefix(req.URL.Path, "/api/authorization") {
            doAuthorization(rw,req)
        }
    }
}

func doAuthorization(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    if authPassed && strings.HasPrefix(req.URL.Path, "/api/authorization/getUserdata") {
        getUserFunction(rw,req)
    }
}
```

Or, alternatively, use the router for all of it:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/api", doApi)
    http.HandleFunc("/api/authorization", doAuthorization)
    http.HandleFunc("/api/authorization/getUserdata", getUserFunction)
}

func doApi(rw, req) {
    // Whatever you'd do for a call to "/api" itself
}

func doAuthorization(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // Whatever you'd do for a call to "/api/authorization" itself
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Time ago I did a Web Application with [Gin Web Framework](https://gin-gonic.github.io/gin/). 
It’s based in a Radix Tree algorithm. 
It's also extremely readable, fast to understand and create web APIs. 
Hope this hepls.